# Python list of dictionaries - adding the dicts with same key names

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

I have a python list like this:

```
user = [
        {'name': 'ozzy', 'quantity': 5},
        {'name': 'frank', 'quantity': 4},
        {'name': 'ozzy', 'quantity': 3},
        {'name': 'frank', 'quantity': 2},
        {'name': 'james', 'quantity': 7},
        ]
```

I am trying to write the code to join the dictionaries with the same name by also adding the quantities. The final list will be that:

```
user = [
        {'name': 'ozzy', 'quantity': 8},
        {'name': 'frank', 'quantity': 6},
        {'name': 'james', 'quantity': 7}
        ]
```

I have tried a few things but I am struggling to get the right code. The code I have written below is somewhat adding the values (actually my list is much longer, I have just added a small portion for reference).

```
newList = []
    quan = 0
    for i in range(0,len(user)):      
        originator = user[i]['name']
        for j in range(i+1,len(user)):
            if originator == user[j]['name']:
                quan = user[i]['quantity'] + user[j]['quantity']
                newList.append({'name': originator, 'Quantity': quan})
```

can you please help me to get the correct code?

Comment: what is the problem with the code you've written? Is the output incorrect? Please give your current and your expected output.

Comment: Should the relative order of the output be maintained?

Comment: @Zinki They gave the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is also straightforward with a standard dictionary. No need for `Counter` or `OrderedDict` here:

```
user = [
        {'name': 'ozzy', 'quantity': 5},
        {'name': 'frank', 'quantity': 4},
        {'name': 'ozzy', 'quantity': 3},
        {'name': 'frank', 'quantity': 2},
        {'name': 'james', 'quantity': 7},
        ]

dic = {}
for item in user:
  n, q = item.values()
  dic[n] = dic.get(n,0) + q
print(dic)

user = [{'name':n, 'quantity':q} for n,q in dic.items()]
print(user)
```

Result:

```
{'ozzy': 8, 'frank': 6, 'james': 7}
[{'name': 'ozzy', 'quantity': 8}, {'name': 'frank', 'quantity': 6}, {'name': 'james', 'quantity': 7}]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working good but when I have a key with a blank like 'name surname' then I can not use it withing dict() but instead {'name surname' : k, 'quantity' : v} fixed that part.

Comment: Good point! As your example didn't show that case, I skipped it. I've edited the answer...

Answer (score 5):

Just count the items in a `collections.Counter`, and expand back to list of dicts if needed:

```
user = [
        {'name': 'ozzy', 'quantity': 5},
        {'name': 'frank', 'quantity': 4},
        {'name': 'ozzy', 'quantity': 3},
        {'name': 'frank', 'quantity': 2},
        {'name': 'james', 'quantity': 7},
        ]

import collections

d = collections.Counter()
for u in user:
    d[u['name']] += u['quantity']

print(dict(d))

newlist = [{'name' : k, 'quantity' : v} for k,v in d.items()]

print(newlist)
```

outputs `Counter` dict first, which is already sufficient:

```
{'frank': 6, 'ozzy': 8, 'james': 7}
```

and the reformatted output using list of dicts:

```
[{'name': 'frank', 'quantity': 6}, {'name': 'ozzy', 'quantity': 8}, {'name': 'james', 'quantity': 7}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing the way the output dictionary looks so that it is actually useable. Consider something like this

```
user = [
        {'name': 'ozzy', 'quantity': 5},
        {'name': 'frank', 'quantity': 4},
        {'name': 'ozzy', 'quantity': 3},
        {'name': 'frank', 'quantity': 2},
        {'name': 'james', 'quantity': 7},
        ]

data = {}
for i in user:
    print(i)
    if i['name'] in data:
        data[i['name']] += i['quantity']
    else:
        data.update({i['name']: i['quantity']})

print(data)
```

> {'frank': 6, 'james': 7, 'ozzy': 8}

Comment: everything in your for loop could be condensed down to a single line using `.get()` - `data[i['name']] = data.get(i['name'], 0) + i['quantity']` - but this still doesn't give OP's desired output

Answer (score 0):

If you need to maintain the original relative order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

user = [
        {'name': 'ozzy', 'quantity': 5},
        {'name': 'frank', 'quantity': 4},
        {'name': 'ozzy', 'quantity': 3},
        {'name': 'frank', 'quantity': 2},
        {'name': 'james', 'quantity': 7},
        ]

d = OrderedDict()
for item in user:
    d[item['name']] = d.get(item['name'], 0) + item['quantity']

newlist = [{'name' : k, 'quantity' : v} for k, v in d.items()]
print(newlist)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'ozzy', 'quantity': 8}, {'name': 'frank', 'quantity': 6}, {'name': 'james', 'quantity': 7}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user = [
    {'name': 'ozzy', 'quantity': 8},
    {'name': 'frank', 'quantity': 6},
    {'name': 'james', 'quantity': 7}
]

reference_dict = {}

for item in user :
    reference_dict[item['name']] = reference_dict.get(item['name'],0) + item['quantity']

#Creating new list from reference dict
updated_user = [{'name' : k , 'quantity' : v} for k,v in reference_dict.items()]

print updated_user
```